# MIPS Assembly sum the value of a string

Tags: assembly, mips

How can i sum up the value of a string with random numbers in MIPS Assembly?

I tried so many things it doesnt work for me.

Can someone help me pls?

```
.data
    correct_number:     .asciiz     "1234 5678 9012 3456"

.text
    la $t0, correct_number
    add $t1, $t1, $zero     #Iterator = 0
    add $t2, $t2, $zero     #Sum = 0
    addi $t3, $t3, 15       #Size = 15

    while:
        bgt $t1, $t3, endwhile

        sll $t9, $t1, 2     #4*i

        addu $t9, $t9, $t0  #correct_number[i)

        lw $t6, 0($t9)      #load the first byte

        addu $s7, $s7, $t6

        addi $t1, $t1, 1    #iterator + 1

        j while
    endwhile:

    li $v0, 1       #Print the sum
    la $a0, ($s7)
    syscall
```

Wrong Result: -738593543

Comment: You need to convert from text to number, or create a text adder as in school, digit by digit.

Comment: `add $t1, $t1, $zero` doesn’t load $t1 with 0; it adds 0 to the current value of $t1.

Comment: Write this in C, then disassemble and get the clue.

Comment: Your code has a couple of issues. First, I wouldn't sum up space, as it isn't a number. Second, do you want to sum up the four 4-digit numbers or each digit individually? Neither work that way. Third, you have a comment `load the first byte` but you use `lw`, so load **word** not **byte**. Fourth, you use s7 without saving or initializing it first. Fifth, loading the address (`la`) of a reg (`s7`)?! If you want to print that value in `s7`, `move` is sufficient. Last, be careful how much code of an assignment you post online. If sb copies it, it might be considered plagiarism on both sides.

Comment: Can you explain me how to get a single digit from a String & avoid the spaces?

Comment: @NaviGOAT Well, for a single digit just use `lb` - _load byte_ as your comment already says. 

To avoid spaces, how would you do it in C (or Java for that matter)? Please have a look at tutorial 6.2 for String-related questions (Hint: ASCII). Also, the length isn't 15, it is longer, given that you already have 4 blocks of 4 characters (=16 chars) + 3 spaces = 17 (Also, don't forget the terminating `NULL`-byte here, so you actually don't need a specific length).

Comment: Perhaps the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582044/mips-assembly-wrong-digit) will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to find the sum of all digits in `correct_number` excluding spaces. For `"1234 5678 9012 3456"` the expected result is `66`.

It always helps to have a high-level pseudocode before attempting the MIPS code. In this case, this is a few lines -

```
sum = 0
$t0 = address of correct_number
while *correct_number is not 0:   // this way, you can avoid '#Size = 15' in your solution
  ch = *correct_number
  if ch is not space:
    ch -= 48                      // convert the ASCII of digit to numeric value
    sum += ch
  correct_number++                // increment string pointer

// now sum contains the sum of all digits.
```

It remains to translate this to MIPS -

```
.data
correct_number:     .asciiz     "1234 5678 9012 3456"

.text
la   $t0, correct_number    # $t0 = address of correct_number
move $t2, $zero             # $t2 = Sum = 0

while:
lb   $t1, ($t0)             # $t1 = load the current byte
beqz $t1, endwhile          # did we reach end of string?
beq  $t1, ' ', continue     # if not, is current char space?
subi $t1, $t1, '0'          # if not, convert the digit char to its numeric value
add  $t2, $t2, $t1          # sum += numeric_value

continue:
addi $t0, $t0, 1            # correct_number++ (increment pointer)
j while                     # and loop

endwhile:
li   $v0, 1                 # $v0 = 1 to print integer in $a0
move $a0, $t2               # move Sum to $a0
syscall                     # and print it


li $v0, 10                  # exit program
syscall
```