# MIPS Assembly wrong digit

Tags: assembly, mips

```
la $a0, number
li $t3, 0     #Iterator = 0
li $v1, 0     #Sum = 0

while:
add $t1, $a0, $t3   #t1 = &A[i]

lb $t1, 0($t1)      # A[i]

beq $t1, $zero, endwhile

add $v1, $v1, $t1       # Sum

addi $t3, $t3, 1        # Iterator + 1

subi $v1, $v1, 48       # ???? Every digit is added with 48, so i have to subtract but why ???

j while
endwhile:

li $v0, 1       #Print the sum
move $a0, $v1 
syscall
```

Can someone pls help me. Why do i have to subtract every digit with 48 to get the right result?
I dont know why its keep adding every time 48 to the digit from my string.
As example i have the String: "1234" if i dont subtract every digit with 48 the result is 202. With subtraction of 48 for every digit the right result is 10.

Comment: Yes, you need to subtract 48 from every digit. Consult an [ascii table](http://asciitable.com). You can see that the characters `0-9` correspond to codes 48-57.

Comment: Oh thanks.. I didnt know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, given a number as a string (say "1234"), you are trying to get the sum of all the digits. "1234" string is stored as following 5 bytes in MIPS memory - 
49, 50, 51, 52, 0

0th byte - decimal 49 (ASCII of 1)
1st byte - decimal 50 (ASCII of 2) .. etc.
nth byte - decimal 0 (ASCII of null character - indicates the end of a string to MIPS)

Consider this line from your code -

```
lb $t1, 0($t1)      # A[i]
```

This loads the byte value at A[i]. In the first iteration, this stores 49 (ASCII of '1'), *not* '1' itself.

Now to get the digit itself from it's ASCII value, we need to subtract ASCII of '0' from it.

that is, ASCII of digit **d** - ASCII of **0** = numeric value of **d** (think about it).
Now ASCII of **0** is 48. That is what you are subtracting.

In its absence, you end up summing the ASCII values of 1, 2, 3, 4, which is 49+50+51+52 = 202